# Where need it call dropCollection using nodejs with mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was doing a server using nodejs, it need get data from mongodb.  I retrieve data after require(../db.js). Somebody said the mongodb needn't be close in nodejs,because nodejs is a single process..... 
My question: Need I call dropCollection to close the collection after invoked the db function many times;and How to do?Where to do that? Please,Thanks.

Comment: drop a collection means delete that collection. Close a connection means close that connection. You must be using db.close() if you want to close a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to drop the collection after invoking db functions,simply call  `db.close()` though it is not needed. But if you want to do it , you can do it as follows:

```
var dropRestaurants = function(db, callback) {
   db.collection('restaurants').drop( function(err, response) {
      console.log(response)
      callback();
   });
};
```